# How can I fix this layer from appearing multiple time when using MERN and CRUD operations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, crud, mern

I am creating a data table using MERN CRUD however when the user hits delete I want a Layer(Modal) to appear and then have the option to click yes or no. The problem that I am having is that the delete button appears more than once in the same id. How do I make it to where it is not like that and just one delete button? Below are all of the times that this layer corresponds with. If anyone can please help me with a better understanding of how to do this or fix it. Thank you
[This is an Image of what the buttons look like for reference of what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2hd5.png)

```
render() {

        const deletebtn = (
        <Box>
            {this.state.alumnis.map((alumni, index) => (
        <Button 
            primary
            icon={<Trash />}
            label="delete"
            onClick={() => this._onClick(alumni._id)}
            
            />
            ))}
            </Box>
            );

        const layer = (this.state.layerActive) ? (
            <Box>
                {this.state.alumnis.map((alumni, index) => (
                <Layer onClose={this._onLayerClose}  align="center" onClickOutside={this._onLayerClose} onEsc={this._onLayerClose} plain animate="slide">
                    <Box pad="large" background="pink" round>
                        <Heading level={4} alignSelf="center">
                            Are you sure you want to delete?
                        </Heading>
                        <Box direction="row" alignSelf="center" pad={{top: "small"}} gap="small">
                            <Button label="no" color="critical-status" type="button" primary color="black" onClick={this._onLayerClose} />
                            <Button label="yes" color="#b22222" type="button" primary onClick={() => this.onDelete(alumni._id)} />
                        </Box>
                    </Box>
                </Layer>
            ))}
            </Box>
        ) : undefined;
```

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
        alumnis: [],
        layerActive: false,
        name: ""
        };
        
        this._onClick = this._onClick.bind(this);
        this._onLayerClose = this._onLayerClose.bind(this);
        
    }
    componentDidMount(){
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/alumnis/detail/${id}`).then((res) => {
        if(res.data.success){
            this.setState({
                name: res.data.alumni.name
            })
        }
    })
    this.getAlumnis()
    }

    _onClick(){
        this.setState({layerActive: true});
    }
    _onLayerClose(){
        this.setState({layerActive: false});
    }
```

```
<TableBody >
            
            {this.state.alumnis.map((alumni, index) => (
                <TableRow>
                
                    <TableCell ><Text size="large" >{index}</Text></TableCell>
                
                <TableCell align="center" alignSelf="center" alignContent="center">
                    <Text size="large">{alumni.name}</Text>
                </TableCell >
                <TableCell><Text size="large">{alumni.year}</Text></TableCell >
                <TableCell><Text size="large">{alumni.accomplishment}</Text></TableCell >
                <TableCell align="center"><Text size="large">{alumni.education}</Text></TableCell >
                <TableCell align="center"><Text size="large">{alumni.career}</Text></TableCell >
                <TableCell align="center"><Text size="large">{alumni.message}</Text></TableCell >
                <TableCell gap="xsmall" direction="row">
                        <Button href={`/edit/${alumni._id}`} color="#FFAA15" >
                            <Box direction="row" align="center" alignSelf="center" gap="xxsmall">
                                <Edit color="#FFAA15" />
                                <Text size="large">Edit</Text>
                            </Box>
                        </Button>

                        <Box>
                            {layer}                    
                        </Box>
                        <Box>
                            {deletebtn}
                        </Box>
                    

    
                       
                </TableCell >
                </TableRow >
            ))}
            </TableBody>
```